# Native SSH client can no longer connect, but scp and PyCharm SSH clients work ok?

Tags: linux, openssh

Really strange problem I am running into today, and I don't remember changing anything. My SSH client hangs when trying to connect to a client (see below output snippit). However, scp works fine to the same address, PyCharm works fine (it has its own SSH client), and other people on my network can SSH in. I can't SSH into any other client either.

```
user@user:~$ ssh user@192.168.1.1 -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
```

Using Ubuntu 16.04.2, openssh-client, no firewall or anything else like that.

* adding scp debug outputs

```
user@user:~$ scp -v cayman@192.168.1.1:FILE .
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.1, user user, command scp -v -f FILE
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:zxclXzh+D5j1+BwcOUly8AChlfh9Hqdoh651rShR7Bo
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:zxclXzh+D5j1+BwcOUly8AChlfh9Hqdoh651rShR7Bo.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@192.168.1.1's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.1 ([192.168.1.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f FILE
Sending file modes: C0664 329835 FILE
Sink: C0664 329835 FILE
FILE                                                                        100%  322KB 322.1KB/s   00:00    
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 1988, received 332744 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10317.9, received 1726971.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: Show us `scp -v` for comparison. + Would `-vvv` show anything more?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, added

Comment: What is in `/home/user/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check my `/home/user/.ssh/config`.

The SSH client reads it, while SCP does not.

Also, your debug log says:

debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *

...so there *is* something (at least two lines) in your user config.

I am not aware of any pranks<sup>1</sup> that could be performed through that file that could prevent connection and do so with the symptoms you observe, but you never know...

---

(1) e.g. setting `IdentityFile` to `/dev/zero`, placing interesting values in SendEnv, playing with UTF-8 'invisible' chars...